# ffmpeg неверный порядок параметров

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg

Требуется преобразовать набор(Матрицы кадров) данных в видеофайл mp4. Для этой цели я использую ffmpeg и popen. Чтобы использовать в качестве входных данных поток ввода испозуются параметры -f rawvideo и -i -.

Первоначально использовался вариант

```
cmd = QString("C://ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -f rawvideo -y -s %1x%2 -r %3 -i - -c:v h264 -pix_fmt rgb24 %4").arg(800).arg(600).arg(FPS).arg(OutFileName);
```

//Выходной файл в формате .mp4

(Команда была составлена ориентируясь на эту запись https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778774/using-ffmpeg-to-losslessly-convert-yuv-to-another-format-for-editing-in-adobe-pr)
Но при этом параметры применятся к входным данным, а выходной файл оказывается пустым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Используя синтаксис {[input_file_options] -i input_url}

cmd = QString("C://ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -f rawvideo -i - -y -s %1x%2 -r %3 -c:v h264 -pix_fmt rgb24 %4").arg(800).arg(600).arg(FPS).arg(OutFileName);
```

Я получаю уже другую ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно прописать команду чтобы покадрово записать видео из матриц?

Comment: Какая версия ffmpeg? Удивительно, что он умудрился выдать хоть что-то — из-за того, что вы не указали абсолютно никаких параметров для rawvideo, он вообще-то должен был свалиться с ошибкой `Picture size 0x0 is invalid`

Comment: Версия 6.1 качал с гитхаба. Параметры для rawvideo это последовательность команд? Вот для того я и задал вопрос чтобы определить верный порядок их расположения.  Перенос -i 
в конец приводит к аналогичному результату

Comment: Параметры входа указываются перед `-i`, параметры выхода указываются перед именем выходного файла. Вообще, что конкретно вы подаёте на вход ffmpeg?

Comment: Матрицу через _popen. fwrite(mat.data,1,sizeof(mat), outw);

Comment: Почему вы пишете mat.data, а размер указываете sizeof(mat)? Вы уверены, что sizeof(mat) точно равен размеру кадра в байтах? (что-то мне подсказывает что нифига не равен) Что такое mat вообще?

Comment: Это скорее всего ошибка, но сначала нужно добиться того чтобы командная строка поняла что данные ей подаются через стандартный ввод. Обновил основной пост.

Comment: Ну вот самая первая команда в текущем её виде (после правок вопроса) выглядит приемлемо, осталось только подать на вход то, что будет соответствовать заявленным вами параметрам